# third party hdmi to vga adapter does not work

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport, vga-adapter

I recently bought an HDMI to VGA adapter and a VGA cable, and when I plug it in it doesn't work properly. I was having problems so I read that the HDMI port on mac does not work, and that you need to use the mini DisplayPort/thunderbolt ports on your mac and that the adapter has to made by apple for it to work properly, is the last statement true? and if it is do apple sell mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cables or adapters?

Comment: Where did you read that HDMI does not work on Mac? And why would you believe something like that?

Comment: I read the the hdmi port on mac emit too little power for it to be used to connect up to a display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those statements are true.

But there is no reason to use adapters when TB2/TB3/USBC on a Mac support DIsplayPort directly.  As long as your monitor supports DP, buy the mDP-to-DP cable of your choice from Amazon and you will be fine.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00C7RJQPY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C7RJQPY)   (mDP to DP)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01J6DT070](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J6DT070)   (USBC to DP)